# how to select all songs when i click playselected?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i get all songs selected when i click playselected button without selecting any songs?

```
</style>
<script language=JavaScript>
function checkall()
{
void(d=document);
void(el=d.getElementsByName('song[]'));
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++)
void(el[i].checked=1)
}
function uncheckall()
{
void(d2=document);
void(e2=d2.getElementsByName('song[]'));
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++)
void(el[i].checked=0)
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="/player.php" target="player">
<table width="747" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" rowspan="6" valign="top">
    </td>
    <td height="120" colspan="3" align="center" valign="top"></td>
    <td width="176" rowspan="6" valign="top"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- movie name -->
    <td width="179" height="150" align="center" valign="top"><h3><font color="#008080">moviename</font></h3>

      <!-- movie Description start (add description in between these tags)-->
<pre>


</pre>      <!-- movie Description end-->
      </td>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><img src="/images/moviename.jpg"></td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="179" height="44" align="center"><input type=submit value="Play Selected"  /></td>
    <td width="86"><input type=button onClick="checkall()" value="Select All" name="button"></td>

    <td width="156"><input type=button onClick="uncheckall()" value="Invert Selection" name="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top"><table height="342" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="423" class="VERDANAFONT">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_1 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_1.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->

            0_1 <br />
          </font></p></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_2 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_2.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->
            0_2 <br />

          </font></p></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_3 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_3.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->
            0_3 <br />
          </font></p></td>

          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_4,/telugusongs/moviename/0_4.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->
            0_4<br />
          </font></p></td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_5 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_5.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->
            0_5 <br />
          </font></p></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>

          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_6 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_6.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->
            0_6<br />
          </font></p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">

<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_7 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_7.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->
            0_7 <br />
          </font></p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td width="423" height="38" align="left" valign="middle"><p> <font color="#339966">
<input type="checkbox" name="song[]" value="0_8 ,/telugusongs/moviename/0_8.mp3" />
            <!-- song names -->

           0_8 <br />
          </font></p></td>
          </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

am explaining clearly... when user select one song and if click on playselect button form will post one song. that is working perfect. but when user didnot select any song any if he clicked on playselected button ,in this situation i want all songs to be selected

Comment: you want your play selected button to select all songs for you?

Comment: yes only if no song is selected

Comment: am explaining clearly...
when user select one song and if click on playselect button form will post one song.
that is working perfect.
but when user didnot select any song any if he clicked on playselected button ,in this situation i want all songs to be selected.

Comment: updated with Demo version and tweaks in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding an **id** to your *playselect button*, something like this should work

**javascript only approach**

```
<input type="Button" id="PlaySelected" value="Play Selected" 
onclick="checklist(myform)"/>//minor changes here made

function checklist(field)
{
   var answer=false;
   for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
   {
     if (field[i].type=="checkbox" && field[i].checked){
        answer=true;
        return false;
     }
   }
   for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
   {
       field[i].checked = true ;
   }
}
```

Also I forgot to mention to you to add the name **"myform"** to your `form` tag: Here is a

[Click here for Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohopo) working version

**jQuery**

```
$('#PlaySelected').click(function()
{
  var answer=false;
  $('input[type='checkbox']').each(function(){
    answer = this.checked;
    if(answer==true)
    {
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('input[type='checkbox']').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Comment: ? im not sure what you're asking you're asking where to add the jquery code?

Comment: refer to http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery for more detail and examples

Comment: Im sorry, i assumed you wanted the answer in jquery, would you rather want it in javascript?

Comment: @musicking- actually jquery is javascript, but its a more slicker and easier way of doing things

Comment: thank you for ur help...........
bracket after song[] is a vector which will contain the address of each song selected to play.

Comment: update your first **<script>** tag to **<script type="text/javascript">**